# Getting null if i don't choose first radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have some code on project Asp.net MVC5:
Models

```
public class Question
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Answer1 { get; set; }
    public string Answer2 { get; set; }
    public int? QuestionID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Question> questions = new List<Question> {
            new Question { ID = 1, name = "What is the capital of Germany" },
            new Question {ID =2 , name ="What is the capital of France" } 
        };
        List<Answer> answers = new List<Answer>
        {
            new Answer {Answer1="London", Answer2 = "Berlin", QuestionID= 1},
            new Answer {Answer1="Paris", Answer2 = "Berlin", QuestionID = 2}
        };
        ViewBag.Answers = answers;
        return View(questions);
    }
}
```

And View Index :

```
@using WebApplication2.Models;
@model List<Question>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.Label(Model[i].name)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ViewBag.Answers.Count; j++)
            {
                if (Model[i].ID == ViewBag.Answers[j].QuestionID)
                {
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(a => Model[i].name, ViewBag.Answers[j].Answer1 as string)
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(a => Model[i].name, ViewBag.Answers[j].Answer2 as string)
                }
            }
        }

    }
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
}
```

after this form i am getting result here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Question> questions)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If i choose both radiobuttons i get values on (List questions), but
If i don't choose first radiobutton i get null, even i choose antoher radiobutton.

I know if I use simple html-helper like
`@Html.RadioButton("GetValue1", ViewBag.Answers[j].Answer1 as string)` and change "post" controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string GetValue1)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

i will get values, but i would like to use StronglyTyped Helper. So, how can i use collections on this project.I need to send String.empty instead of null.

Comment: can you post how HTML is generated?

Comment: ``<form action="/" method="post"><label for="What_is_the_capital_of_Germany">What is the capital of Germany</label>
<input name="[0].name" type="radio" value="London" /><input name="[0].name" type="radio" value="Berlin" /><label for="What_is_the_capital_of_France">What is the capital of France</label>
<input name="[1].name" type="radio" value="Paris" /><input name="[1].name" type="radio" value="Berlin" />    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution that works

**View** Change your form to the code below

This basically uses normal html tags for binding

```
@using WebApplication2.Models;
@model List<Question>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var answers = (List<Answer>)ViewBag.Answers;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <br />
    foreach (var question in Model)
    {
        @Html.Label(question.name)
        {
            foreach (var answer in answers)
            {
                if (question.ID == answer.QuestionID)
                {                
                    <input type="radio" name="@question.controlName" value="@answer.Answer1"/>@answer.Answer1 
                    <input type="radio" name="@question.controlName" value="@answer.Answer1"/>@answer.Answer2
                }
            }
        }

        <br />

    }
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
}
```

**Model** I modified your model to give a unique name to each radio group

```
public class Question
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string controlName { get; set; } //this will be the name in the input field
}
```

**Controller** Here I don't really know how you are generating the list but I expect it to come from the db

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //here I added the controlName variable to the Question, this is better to identify each question by name
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Question> questions = new List<Question> {
            new Question { ID = 1, name = "What is the capital of Germany", controlName = "germany"},
            new Question {ID =2 , name ="What is the capital of France", controlName = "france"}
        };
        List<Answer> answers = new List<Answer>
        {
            new Answer {Answer1="London", Answer2 = "Berlin", QuestionID= 1},
            new Answer {Answer1="Paris", Answer2 = "Berlin", QuestionID = 2}
        };
        ViewBag.Answers = answers;
        return View(questions);
    }
}

//Here am using FormCollection to receive the inputs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection questions)
{
    List<string> controlNames = new List<string>{"germany","france"}; //this is supposed to come from the db if db is in use
    //next create a dictionary of string and string for the controlName and the answer selected for it
    Dictionary<string, string> userAnswer = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var controlName in controlNames)
    {
        userAnswer.Add(controlName, questions[controlName]);
    }

    //Manipulate the dictionary here and save to the db
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, FormCollection  was very helpful for me.` foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
   {
      var value = formCollection[key];
      // etc.
   }`